# Recipe to deploy the .ipk for other developers

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe, openembedded

I have a recipe (lets say my_package_1.0.bb) that builds libraries and populates sysroot with libraries and headers I need for development. 
I also see that .ipk for my package is created under build/tmp/deploy/ipk/.

My requirement is, I want to share the libraries, headers and a recipe that deploys these in my customer's sysroot directory (for their development), but not the sources for my package. What is the best way to handle this?

Is there a way that I share the .ipk and some recipe to install the .ipk?

P.S: customer intends to develop applications using the interfaces in my header and libraries. customer has not licensed the sources for my package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

using `OPKG` to install the `.ipk` package you generated.

Start by creating an Yocto Linux Image with `OPKG` program and `package-management`

In `conf/local.conf`
add these, particularly, `package-management` in `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` and `opkg` in `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`.

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm package_ipk"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks ssh-server-openssh package-management"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " opkg "
```

After created an image, create a package manifest:

`bitbake package-index`

Create a server, `apache2`, for example. And link your ipk to that server:

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

`sudo ln -s /path/to/build-x11/tmp/deploy/ipk /var/www/html/my-repo`

Set up and Test OPKG
C
reate file `opkg.conf` in `/etc/opkg/`

Edit the opkg.conf to something like the following 
Note: Replace 192.168.0.102 to the IP of the build station (the apache2 server you use); for example

```
src/gz all http://192.168.0.102/all
src/gz cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6 http://192.168.0.102/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6
src/gz cortexa9hf-vfp-neon http://192.168.0.102/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon
```

Test `OPKG`

```
opkg
opkg update
opkg upgrade
opkg install my_package
```

[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byB-akYRl9s)

[Documentation](http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=Yocto:_Opkg_Package_Management_System_Set_Up)